# How to get human-readable value from optionset in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I use dataverse as POWER BI data source. But i can not get human-readable value from optionset even use direct query model when i get data from dataverse.
The table account has column key in dataverse, I get data both use import and direct query,but both of the two model, the column keyname are empty,but the column key like value like 899xxxxxx

Thanks very much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Step: “Get data” and select the “Dataverse” as datasource, then select a table. I try both import and directly query modle. Both of the modle, i only can ge the key value,but can not get the keyname.